# What are the changes to EVM from Constantinople fork and later forks?

Tags: contract-development, evm, hardforks, constantinople, istanbul

What are the changes to EVM from Constantinople fork and later forks?
Could you tell me which commit in git?
Or Could you provide a list?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is not a single commit in a git, as there are at least two different Ethereum clients (Go Ethereum, Parity) - implementing these changes.

I would say a better place to dig into this history is EIPs and see what are finals and which where the forks they were released in:

https://eips.ethereum.org/